# FileProvider can't retrieve image from storage in Android

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to retrieve an image from the storage of the app.
I have a library that stores an image in `file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.android.debug/cache/cropped4227942271894219596.jpg`.

I'm trying to retrieve the image by doing the following:

`getUriForFile(context, context.applicationInfo.packageName + ".fileprovider", File(imageUri))` but all I get is:

`Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/data/user/0/com.myapp.android.debug/cache/cropped4227942271894219596.jpg`

My `provider_paths.xml` is:

`<paths>
  <files-path
      name="internal_files"
      path="/cache" />
</paths>`

Does somebody know what the problem could be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding below code in `filepath.xml` as cache files needs to be mentioned with `cache-path`

```
<cache-path name="cache_files" path="."  />
```

Comment: hope you are creating file using `File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "your_file.ext");` and have provided `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Comment: well I don't create, it's the library the one creating it; it is created and it exists tho.